# gRPC - Exposing Public APIs

Tags: api, rest, rpc, http2, grpc

Feb 26, Google announced gRPC:
http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com.br/2015/02/introducing-grpc-new-open-source-http2.html

In that post they said: "Internally at Google, we are starting to use gRPC to expose most of our public services through gRPC endpoints as part of our long term commitment to HTTP/2.

If they are starting to use gRPC to expose their public APIs... What they are using to communicate internally between applications?

Is there a specific problem in using gRPC also for internal communication between apps?

Answer (score 4):

There's no problem with using gRPC for internal communication - it's really great for that in fact. There are some applications that are looking to do that at Google, and more will follow as older technologies are phased out.

Comment: A year later, Craig, I'm curious how much internal gRPC usage there is at Google.  I'm trying to evaluate it for my project but it would be a lot easier if I could point to a successful large user (e.g. Google).

Comment: We mentioned several non-Google projects in the GA blog post: http://www.grpc.io/blog/gablogpost